# File Upload working on PHP4 but not PHP5

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I have an application designed in a local install (PHP4/MySQL) and it works perfectly. Since I moved it to a live install (PHP5/MySQL) I have had nothing but issues! I fixed any global variable issues (lead me to learn PDOs so not a bad thing!) without turning global variables on, so the only issue I have is with file uploads. I tried an isset test for $_file and it looks like the variable was never set? Any ideas?

Here is the form data:

```
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="script_add_product.php" >   

     <input class="cp_forms_upload" type="file" name="full_image" />

     <input class="cp_formsButton" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Add Product" /></form>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
    $full_image_url = $_FILES["full_image"]["name"];     

    if ((($_FILES["full_image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["full_image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["full_image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["full_image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["full_image"]["size"] < 400000))
      {
     if ($_FILES["full_image"]["error"] > 0)
      {
       echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["full_image"]["error"] . "<br />";
       }
     else
       {
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["full_image"]["name"] . "<br />";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["full_image"]["type"] . "<br />";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["full_image"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
      echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["full_image"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />"; 

      if (file_exists("../Uploads/" . $_FILES["full_image"]["name"]))
       {
         echo $_FILES["full_image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } 
      else 
         {
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["full_image"]["tmp_name"],
         "../Uploads/" . $_FILES["full_image"]["name"]);
         echo "Stored in: " . "../Uploads/" . $_FILES["full_image"]["name"];
     echo "<br /><br /><br />" . $full_image_url;
         }
       }

      }

      else
      {
     echo "Invalid file";
       }
```

Thanks folks :)

Comment: What does $_POST output? var_dump($_POST);

Comment: are you sure that image you are trying to upload is not bigger than upload_max_filesize value?

Comment: mrok, I have tested images just 20kb in size. Upload_max_filesize is 16M. 

Bono, how do I var_dump?

Comment: I think @Bono thought about var_dump($_FILES). What is your current php5 version? latest 5.4.5?  are you using suhosin?

Comment: @mrock - version is 5.2.17 but I'm using third party hosting. Not sure if they're using suhosin?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check in your `php.ini` for if `file_uploads` is set to `On`.

```
; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://ph .net/file-uplollow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On
```

Comment: Hi, phpinfo() tells me file_uploads are on?

Answer (score 0):

See `php.ini` config.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = "...../tmp"

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

Also it might be useful `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` config params in `php.ini`.
more: [Handling file Uploads -> Common Pitfalls](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php)

Make sure that folder `"../Uploads/"` exists and has permissions to write for user under apache/nginx work (`www_data` or some like)

Comment: Hi, this is the results from phpinfo() if this helps? 

upload_max_filesize 16M 16M
upload_tmp_dir no value no value

Comment: I test your code. It works!.. So I think it is no permitions or no such folder. Its will be helpfully to see the logs, if posible.
If you can't view logs, just insert `var_dump(...);` on each step. Or `echo 'xbcvxcvx';die;` to see where it fault

Comment: Also you can to set your own error_handler (if no already use) to log the error by yourself to somefile... - for the future.
[set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: I will try error handling on any line and see if I can narrow it down. The folder exists and the $_FILE ISSET when tested and no luck when I try a direct link (http://www... etc) to the folder. I'm thinking it must be a server issue but if Wordpress can run on it...

Comment: @Nikola K, the folder exists alright. Not sure if CHMOD works with Windows Server - tried it anyway: 500 'SITE CHMOD 755 upload': command not understood

Comment: Can you paste the line in which error faults and the error message ?

Answer (score -1):

Could this be the problem? An additional '(' bracket in this section:

```
if (($_FILES["full_image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["full_image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["full_image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["full_image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["full_image"]["size"] < 400000))
```

Comment: @Sarke I corrected it in my answer. I'm referring to the one OP posted. Check the code he supplied

Comment: @asprin I am using the code from here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp and ironically when I put the code through a PHP IDE it tells me there's issues with this line:

//&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

When it is checking the extensions. So I comment it out but makes no odds with the final result.

Comment: @asprin His brackets match, yours don't. Notice that it's a few OR and then an AND, with the ORs being grouped together. See the second to last line has an extra closing bracket to close the OR group.